# How to Change the background gradient according the Temperature (Value)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I looking for some JS or css3 plugin or solution to change background color depends on Temperature (Value).
For example if my Temperature is 14℃ so the background will be with some blue color if I starting to increment the  Temperature and now it 30℃ so the background will change smoothly to some orange color etc...
Thanks.

Comment: Not sure if there's any API that provides the device's ambient temperature. You will need to use an online API and query the device area's temperature using the [geolocation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/WebAPI/Using_geolocation).

Comment: Check out this example: [link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xasfw)

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the color code as described in the [What Is Color Blending?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb976070.aspx) article on MSDN. I made a quick and dirty example on [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/dosedeme/18/edit). In the example I used a simple gradient with two steps. You should add another step with an orange color in the middle for a nicer representation.